# 24 hour clock to standard

Tags: c++, clock

I am writing a program for class where it converts from military time to standard. Everything else seems to be working fine until I type in 60 for the minutes. For example if I type 23:60 it gives me 11:60 PM which is incorrect. How do I fix this? I tried checking if minutes == 60  to reset minutes to 0 but I cant figure it out.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

void inputData(int&, int&, char&); // this function asks users to input 
information
void convertData(int&, int&, char&); // this converts the military time to 
standard time
int outputData(int&, int&, char&);  // this function puts all the other 
information together to output certain data
int main ()
{
int hours, minutes;
char am_pm;
char trueValue;

do
{
    inputData(hours, minutes, am_pm); // calls to input function
    convertData(hours, minutes, am_pm); // calls to the conversion function
    outputData(hours, minutes, am_pm); // calls to function that outputs all 
the data
    cout << "Would you like another conversion? Type Y or y to repeat." << 
endl;
    cin >> trueValue;
}

while (trueValue == 'y'|| trueValue == 'Y');

if (trueValue != 'y' || trueValue != 'Y')
    cout << "Thanks for using this converter. Have a nice day." << endl;

return 0;
}

void inputData (int &hours, int &minutes, char &am_pm)
{
cout << "Please enter hours (less than or equal to 24): "; // ask user to 
input hours.
do
{
    cin >> hours;
    if (hours > 24)
        cout << "ERROR! Must be less than 24" << endl;
} 
while (hours > 24); // end of hours loop

cout << "Please enter minutes (less than or equal to 60): "; // ask user to 
input minutes.
do
{
    cin >> minutes;
    if (minutes > 60)
    {
        cout << "Must be less than 60. Try again!" << endl;
    }
}
while (minutes > 60); //end of minutes loop
cout << endl;
cout << "You have entered: " << hours << ":" << minutes; // display what 
user inputs together.
cout << endl;

}

void convertData(int &hours, int &minutes, char &am_pm)
{ 
if (minutes == 60)
{
    hours++; // add an hour to 'hours'
    minutes = minutes/60;

}


if (hours < 12)
{
    hours = 12-12+1;
}
if (hours > 12)
{
    hours = hours - 12; // subtracts anything bigger than 12 to get standard 
time. Anything over 12 is PM according to project instruction
    am_pm = 'P';
}
else
if (hours == 12) 
{
    am_pm = 'P';
}
else
am_pm = 'A';
}


int outputData(int &hours, int &minutes, char &am_pm)
{   

if (am_pm == 'P')
cout <<"Your standard time is: " << hours << ":" << minutes << " P.M" << 
endl;
else
cout <<"Your standard time is: " << hours << ":" << minutes << " A.M" << 
endl;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, 23:60 isn't a valid time, so your program should just print "Please enter a valid time".

Comment: Oh, your code needs to check for minutes >= 60 and error out.

Comment: Ever heard of the [modulus](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) (`%`) function? It would make your code a lot simpler (e.g. to convert `23:12` to normal time, take the hour part (`23`) and do `23 % 12`, which returns `11`).

Comment: Your code for minutes is wrong. Valid values for minutes is 0-59, not 0-60. There is no such time as *0160*; the time then would be *0200*.(I hour + 60 minutes is not *0160*. Fix your logic and there is no problem with your code.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of places you test for `minutes > 60`.  Try `minutes >= 60` instead.

Same with `hours > 24`.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement for minutes being > 60. Change it to >= 60. Currently your if statement is accepting 60 as a valid condition for minutes.